¿Por qué en Python al ejecutar .pop() devuelve 1 en todas las impresiones?
numbers = set({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
number_remove = numbers.pop()
print(number_remove)


Hola Nahuel, esto es [es.so], el idioma del sitio es el español, debes publicar tus preguntas/respuestas en este idioma.

El pop() remueve un elemento del conjunto. Sucede que el elemento elegido es el "1". Si pruebas con otros valores ({10, 20, ... }) verás cambiar el resultado.

Supongo que lo que te extraña es que pop() parezca actuar de forma determinista, en el sentido de que parece extraer siempre los items en el mismo orden cuando los conjuntos en Python son colecciones no ordenadas, que no mantienen el orden de inserción y, efectivamente, esto está especificado así por la documentación por lo que no se puede nunca asumir ningún orden en ellos.
Esto no significa que no muestren indicios de cierto orden, obviamente pop() no aleatoriza al extraer un item, los elementos tienen un orden interno en la tabla hash (generalmente meros arrays) determinado en gran medida por el algoritmo hash.
A grandes rasgos, al insertar un item en una tabla hash  lo que se hace es aplicar una función resumen al item a insertar, a continuación el hash se mapea a un indice válido de la tabla aplicándole una máscara (donde la operación módulo suele estar implicada) y en esa posición se almacena el item (o una referencia al mismo). Cuando se busca un elemento en el conjunto se calcula su hash, se aplica las máscara y obtenemos el indice que debería ocupar, basta con mirar si en esa posición de la tabla esta o no el item, por eso las búsquedas son O(1) en promedio. Todo esto en realidad es algo más complicado por la necesidad de redimensionar la tabla, manejar colisiones hash, etc, pero es la idea general.
Lo importante es que cualquier orden que parezca existir es resultado de la implementación, especialmente de la función hash y esta puede cambiar, no solo entre las implementaciones de Python (PyPy, Jython, Stackless, etc) sino incluso entre versiones de CPython sin previo aviso.
Ciertamente en tu ejemplo, vemos algo de esto:
>>> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
>>> numbers.pop()
1
>>> numbers.pop()
2
>>> numbers.add(1)
>>> numbers.pop()
3
>>> numbers.pop()
4

Pareciera que pop() extrae siguiendo el orden de inserción, pero no, en realidad:
>>> numbers = {5, 1, 3, 0, 4, -1}
>>> numbers.pop()
0
>>> numbers.pop()
1
>>> numbers.pop()
3
>>> numbers.pop()
4
>>> numbers.pop()
5
>>> numbers.pop()
-1

Y si el conjunto es aún más heterogéneo, el orden es cada vez menos intuitivo:
>>> numbers = {10000, "foo", -13, 415, "hola"}
>>> numbers
{'foo', 10000, 'hola', -13, 415}

El orden de los itemns está determinado en primera instancia por el resultado de la función hash sobre ellos y la posterior máscara, que determinan donde se insertan esos items en la tabla. Obviamente, si inicializas un conjunto siempre igual con los mismos items y en el mismo orden, como a = {1, 2}, si la función hash es la misma y determina que el indice de inserción del 1 es menor que el del 2, se insertaran siempre en ese orden en la tabla al crear el set y por tanto pop() o print() parecerán funcionar de forma determinista.
La cosa está en entender que mañana puede que esto no pase porque no es una característica del lenguaje, solo un detalle de implementación, y por supuesto, en el momento que insertas o eliminas elementos a posteriori y empiezan a entrar en en juego redimensionamientos de la tabla, mitigación de colisiones, etc, dos conjuntos con los mismos items posiblemente mostraran diferente "orden".
Para añadir más incertidumbre aún, una practica común para dificultar ataques de colisión es randomizar las funciones hash entre ejecuciones, por lo que te puedes encontrar resultados completamente distintos entre ejecuciones usando el mismo intérprete.

Si quieres que la extracción sea aleatoria (pseudoaleatoria realmente) no dependas de la implementación de los conjuntos, aleatoriza la extracción explícitamente usando las funciones del módulo random, en cuyo caso los conjuntos no suelen ser el mejor contenedor.
Si por contra quieres mantener el orden de inserción pero no quieres perder las ventajas de las tablas hash, en cuanto a eficiencia en búsquedas por ejemplo, puedes usar un diccionario con valores dummies si quieres una solución simple, esto a partir de Python 3.7 donde la implementación de los diccionarios cambio.

Una observación, tu código:
numbers = set({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})

es redundante, numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} ya crea un conjunto, no necesitas usar el builtin (constructor de tipo) set().

Las operaciones pop deberían actuar siempre sobre pilas ordenadas para obtener el primer o el último elemento de la pila. No tiene mucho sentido aplicarlo en conjuntos sin orden definido más allá de obtener un elemento cualquiera (que no aleatorio). Si importa el orden, mejor usar otras colecciones como diccionarios, deque o heapq . Un pequeño detalle: los diccionarios son pilas de tipo LIFO. Al extraer elementos, se hace desde el último introducido al primero. Si se quiere usar una pila FIFO, más natural, mejor usar deque u OrderedDicts.

@ChemaCortes totalmente de acuerdo,  el método es ciertamente útil en varios escenarios pero el nombre del mismo es discutible, a eso hay que añadir  dict.pop() también difiere, el método similar a set.pop() en diccionarios era más bien dict.popitem(), que ahora (Python >= 3.7) sigue el orden LIFO como comentas.
